# Python Joblib Parallel: Unbalanced Parallel Processing

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, joblib

I have a dataframe that needs to be applied some computations. To reduce time, I divided dataframe into 4 subset and store them in list. Then I tried to apply my process to each df subset using Parallel and delayed from joblib. Line is below:

Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(*process_name*)(*df_subset*) for *df_subset* in *df_list*)

But the problem is that passed time for each process are super unstable and unbalanced. (Usually, last thread takes too much time.) Image is : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yagep.png)

Why does this happen? And how to fix this? What could be the alternatives ?
(Windows 10, Python 3.10.7, joblib 1.2.0, pandas 1.5.3, numpy 1.24.2)

What I expect is balancing process time in each thread and reduce process time in general.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)